# Comparação entre datas em PHP

Tags: php

Preciso de uma ajuda com a lógica, mas, não consigo montá-la em PHP (pois, não quero usar este processo com mysqli). No exemplo a seguir, seria o problema que enfrento, basicamente.

```
$hoje = date("Y-m-d"); // Retorna data atual (2018-03-15) formato americano
$inicio_evento = $row['inicio']; // Retorna data 2018-03-15
$fim_evento = $row['fim']; // Retorna data 2018-03-20
```

Como comentei acima, o que preciso sanar em relação a lógica é... Se a data de hoje estiver entre as datas `$inicio_evento` e `$fim_evento`, então o valor é `true`.

O problema está nesta lógica que não consigo montar (com IF / ELSE ), e acredito que talvez seja porque estou a confundir os Operadores de comparação.

```
if(strtotime($inicio_evento) == strtotime($hoje) OR strtotime($fim_evento) >= strtotime($hoje)) {
// CODE
}
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma ajudinha?

Comment: Você pode usar o principio da transitividade para verificar se a data atual esta entre as datas de inicio e fim.. ou seja.. se A > B e C > B, logo C > A. para o seu caso você pode verificar.. if ($data_fim >= $hoje && $hoje >= $data_inicio) { true }

Comment: Rapaz... EU TE AMO! Ficou exatamente como eu precisava!